# django manage.py migrate raises AttributeError

Tags: python, django, django-south

When I try to migrate my db, I'm getting this error:

```
Running migrations for easy_thumbnails:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for easy_thumbnails.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/south/management/commands/migrate.py", line 111, in handle
    ignore_ghosts = ignore_ghosts,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/south/migration/__init__.py", line 233, in migrate_app
    migrator.load_initial_data(target, db=database)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 222, in load_initial_data
    self.post_1_6(target, db)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 240, in post_1_6
    old_cache = django.db.models.loading.cache
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'loading'
```

Apps versions are:

```
Django  1.6.2
Easy thumbnails 1.4
Mptt    0.5.5
Pymorphy    0.5.6
Python  2.7.5
Pytils  0.3dev
South   0.8.4
Suit    0.2.5
```

It's looks like not easy_thumbnails problem, because when I try to migrate my django-allauth  it raises the same error.
Please, help me!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your django package was broken. Check that there is python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py file in your environment. Or just reinstall django package.

```
pip install -U --force-reinstall django
```

Comment: Same error, but it does not helped me :(